# Calculate bits to represent an enum at compile time

Tags: c++, enums, bit-fields

I need to compact my structure for saving memory, and I got a data structure like this:

```
enum class Foo {
  F1,
  F2,
  F3,
  FEnd,
};

struct Bar {
  bool b: 1;
  Foo foo : 2; // Foo has 3 elements, 2 bits can represent them
};
```

and there still chances that the elements of `Foo` will increase, so I don't want to hard code `Foo foo:2` and change it each time `Foo` has added an element.

currently I got a solution:`constexpr static int i = 32 - __builtin_clz(static_cast<int>(Foo::FEnd));` but this is way too ugly and not portable.

So any suggestions?

Comment: RAM is cheap. Saving a few bits is rarely worth the hassle.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly the problem is. You can implement `clz(x)` naively in a `constexpr` function, see e.g https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_first_set#CLZ for the algorithm. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: Aren't enums in C++ immutable? Why are you worried about someone adding more enum fields to `Foo`, does that actually change the size of each enum value?

Comment: @smac89 The point is more likely that the bitfield size should be automatically correct when the programmer adds elements to the enum definition to avoid bugs.

Comment: @uneven_mark I think you are right, I should write my own `constexpr int clz(x)` for portable reason

Comment: @reavenisadesk You also want to calculate the rounded log2 instead of subtracting `clz(x)`. That saves you having to figure out the number of bits in the underlying type and is trivial to implement with a shift-by-one loop and test against zero as condition.

Comment: @reavenisadesk There will be a `constexpr` `std::log2p1` in C++20. Maybe you can use it with experimental `-std=c++2a` support in your compiler. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/log2p1

Answer (score 0):

Since C++ standard do not mention about the `constexpr` math library, the solution is:

```
constexpr uint64_t bits(const uint64_t x) {
  int i = 64;
  uint64_t mask = 0x8000000000000000;
  while (i > 0) {
    if ((mask & x) != 0) return i;
    i--;
    mask /= 2; // do not use >>, which is a non-constexpr in standard.
  }
  return 1;
}
```

then the example code will like this:

```
struct Bar {
  bool b: 1;
  Foo foo : bits(static_cast<int>(Foo::FEnd) - 1);
};
```

If you are using GCC, there's a built-in constexpr log2(x), then the code will be:

```
struct Bar {
  bool b: 1;
  Foo foo : (int)std::log2(static_cast<int>(Foo::FEnd) - 1) + 1;
};
```

**Edit**: the GCC version implementation of `std::log2(x)` is:

```
template<typename _Tp>
    constexpr typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<__is_integer<_Tp>::__value, 
                                              double>::__type
    log2(_Tp __x)
    { return __builtin_log2(__x); }
```

**Edit2**: as @uneven_mark mentioned, `std::log2(x)` returns `double` and may lead to errors depends on the input, so suggestion is to custom `constexpr` functions with checks even using GCC.

Comment: Is `std::log2` a typo? Because that is not GCC specific, but a standard function. It returns a `double` though, so it cannot be used as the size of a bitfield.

Comment: Hi @uneven_mark, I add the GCC implementation to the answer, and the return type is a typo. I have fixed this. The codes write in my answer works well on my side (gcc 7.4.0)

Comment: Yes, with the explicit cast to `int` is does compile and *probably* works, but it only works as long as the size of the `enum` is exactly representable in `double` and as long as `std::log2` doesn't introduce any error to the result, which it may do since it is a floating point function. It might be true that the GCC implementation does not introduce any error if the result is exactly representable, but there is no guarantee. That is why `std::log2p1`, which properly works on integers, will be introduced in C++20.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I custom my function with more checks instead of using `std::log2` in this case even if I used GCC. I will update my answer to warn this.